# RestSharp RestResponse returns null from Controller

Tags: null, return, deserialization, restsharp

I have a controller with a get function that returns a model to the client, if I debug this code on the controller the model properties are well set but when it returns to the client it's not null but the properties are.. I'm sure they are set before the return.. here is my Controller code..

```
public DiskContentModelList Get([FromUri] string token)
    {
        var myFileList = new DiskContentModelList();
        var account = CheckPermissions(token);
        if (CheckCuenta(account))
        {
            //Mandar todos los archivos de la cuenta                
            var myFiles = new List<DiskContentModel>();

            myFiles.Add(new DiskContentModel(1, "foto", "dir"));
            myFiles.Add(new DiskContentModel(1, "video", "dir"));
            myFiles.Add(new DiskContentModel(1, "music", "dir"));

            myFileList.FileList = myFiles;
            return myFileList;
        }
        return myFileList;
    }
```

Here is my Client Code..

```
private void FormFileExplorerLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myRestClient = new RestClient(@"http://localhost:1840/");
        var myRestRequest = new RestRequest("api/files?token=" + Program.MyToken, Method.GET);
        //myRestRequest.AddUrlSegment("token", Program.MyToken);
        var response = myRestClient.Execute<DiskContentModelList>(myRestRequest);
        foreach (var diskModel in ((DiskContentModelList)response.Data).FileList)
            TreeExplorer.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(((DiskContentModel)diskModel).Name));       
    }
```

And here is the Model..

```
public class DiskContentModelList
{
    public List<DiskContentModel> FileList;
}
```

And here is the restsharp example for this

```
// or automatically deserialize result
// return content type is sniffed but can be explicitly set via RestClient.AddHandler();
RestResponse<Person> response2 = client.Execute<Person>(request);
var name = response2.Data.Name;
```

On this website http://restsharp.org/

Comment: Is the model shared by the client and the API?

Comment: Hi Bruno, no but I made a copy of the Api Model on my Winforms Project, I ended up using Json.net library it's very easy and it worked perfect, thanks Bruno